# Unable to add field to existing view

Tags: views, 6, entities

I had previously created a view which is a list of nodes of type 'Banner'. I have added an extra field to the content type, and I have attempted to add this to the view, which seems as if it works ie. adds to the fields list, and reflects the changes in the live preview.

But then the live page doesn't reflect the changes, ie. the new text fields dont show up and the fields aren't populated in the `$row` or `$fields` variables in the views-view-fields.... theme files when debugging.

Also, when I go back to edit the view the new added fields are not there, so it seems as though they haven't been inserted into the database.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. Confirm you added the field to the right content type and save the changes
2. Make sure you added the field to right view "display" and save the changes
3. Clear the cache of the whole site
4. Make sure if you are using field permissions that they are properly set
5. If you are using a template file for the view make sure to add the new field.

Comment: 1. Field is correct as the live preview of the view is showing the new field value.
2. There is only one display the default as it is themed.

Comment: 3. Cleared the cache, both View and 'Performance' caches

Comment: And what happen?

Comment: 5. I have debugged the view variables in the theme ($row, $fields), and the new field isn't there, so its failing before the theming.

Comment: I haven't checked permissions which I will do now

Comment: does the new field has values one the nodes shown in the view?

Comment: So it was the permissions - I didn't have 'View' set for the new fields.

Comment: Perfect, glad it works.